# how to retrieve node values in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

given a simple sequential, what is the call needed to get all node values for a given data row. For example:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_moons
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
X, y = make_moons(n_samples=1000, noise=0.25, random_state=0)
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(4, input_dim=2, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(Adam(learning_rate=0.05),
              'binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, verbose=0)
```

I do not want to calculate manually using the weights, I want to see what "model" does both before and and after activation.
Thanks everybody